# Binlog can't be enabled

Tags: mysql

Today, i want my binlog to be enabled, i've changed my `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d`(Debian 9 and mysql 5.7) like this:
[image]

and then i restart mysql service by `sudo service mysql restart`, but it still does not work:
[image]

it's so sad, pls help me, thks very much

Comment: text is the preferred option for error messages.  https://dba.stackexchange.com for database questions too. Include your mysql error log (as text by editing the question). It might indicate something.

Comment: i am sorry for forgetting push error log. i had checked my error log but it is null